# Problem in simulation results in PSPICE using LM3880 sequencer

Tags: power-electronics, pspice, power-sequencing

When simulating this simple sequencer circuit in PSPICE, I obtained these results which are not the wanted ones:

[image: schematic and results]

I was supposed to have sequences but here I don't know what it is. The right sequence is this one:

[image]

The value of C1 is designed according the datasheet information, for 56µF EN pin will be power-up after 10ms then the power-up sequence will be generated. But as you can see, the EN pin isn't pulled after 10ms neither the sequences are released.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve never used an LM3880 for power sequencing.

I have however used a Silego Greenpak, programmed for my specific needs, and got reset and other functions in the bargain. I’ve even used one to make an LPDDR4 sequence, which is very fussy about power up and power down.

If your regulators have PGOOD flags, then you don’t even need that - diode logic is more than good enough, and absolutely predictable.